# Layout page is not displayed, working in other Views except index. C# ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Hi fellow stackoverflowers.

Long story short, I am currently building an User interface in ASP.net Core MVC. I have created an Action controller that returns an view. Which looks as following.

```
public class VehicleHomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IVehicleHomeService _vehicleHomeService;

    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public VehicleHomeController(IVehicleHomeService vehicleHomeService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this._mapper = mapper;
        this._vehicleHomeService = vehicleHomeService;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async  Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
    {
        var vehicleHome = await _vehicleHomeService.GetVehicleHomeById(id);

        var vehicleHomeResource = _mapper.Map<VehicleHome, VehicleHomeViewModel>(vehicleHome);

        return View(vehicleHomeResource);
    }
}
```

Returning the Index view works like a flow. It uses the layoutpage properly. However when creating the Edit View the Layout is not displayed properly. Both action controllers looks the same in the code that provides the layout.

```
@{
     Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

I've searched for an answer. One common solution was defining layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";.
However this does not work for my application. Does anyone had any similar problems or any tips?

Comment: what do you mean by this *Layout is not displayed properly*? also you should share your `Edit.cshtml`, looks like it's `Layout` is set to null. Usually the `Layout` is set in `_ViewStart.cshtml` for all the views in the affected scope. So your `Edit.cshtml` may be somehow out of that scope or has its `Layout` explicitly set to `null` somewhere.

Comment: Hi King king thanks for your response, I've rephrased my question now thanks for the input. I have stated that the layout the code for providing the layout attribute is the same for both Index and Edit. Hence i did not Provide Edit.cshtml and only the code for providing the layout. Thanks for the heads up about the scope i will look into it and se if it will solve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

The path for finding the layout CSS and Logos then went wrong. The problem is that the code tries to get custom CSS and logos inside PathForTheApplicationLocalHost/Edit/images/logo.svg. And PathForTheApplicationLocalHost/Edit/css/custom.css.

While the correct path should be PathForTheApplicationLocalHost/css/custom.css. I solved this by defining the following inside _Layout.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/custom.css">
```

This made the path correct (PathForTheApplicationLocalHost/css/custom.css) from calling layout in the Edit view.